# how to delay application quit time in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, apple-push-notifications, quit

I want to register my app for push notification when my application terminates so i think if i delay my app quitting time it could be possible.Does someone knows how to delay application quitting time? I think this method

```
[self performSelector:(SEL)aSelector onThread:(NSThread *)thr withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait];
```

will do my job but i don't know how to use this method if someone knows please tell.I need to send some data to a server along with registering for Push Notification  when my app quits.

Comment: I don't think that's possible; even if you're code is not finished executing the OS will close it after a few seconds if it wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For push notification it is better to register when the app first starts and then send the push token to your server in the background.  However, if you have a good reason why you need to do the registration just as the app terminates, I believe you can do this if you are using iOS 4.  iOS 4 has a new feature called "task finishing" that allows an app to stay running for a few minutes after the user closes it so that it may finish up any tasks it was in the middle of (such as saving data).

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why you would want to do this.  If it were even possible it would be extremely annoying for a user to tap the home button and the app to take x amount of time to shut down. This time 'x' being dependent on the server connection creates even more user headache.

Apple have the home button exit apps immediately for a reason.

If you want to register the Push Notifications like you suggest, do it while the app is running.  If your worrying that they won't be properly set if the user exits prematurely... don't. 
As users, we all know there are sometimes consequences of exiting a program without giving it time to save your settings.

Comment: Your application will terminate approximately 5 seconds after you get the termination notification.